# An alternative to negative

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, margin, responsive

I'm using negative margin for making images closer together.Without margin:
[image: Without margin]With margin:
[image: With margin]margin:
[image: margin]
it works perfectly in full screen. But after making screen smaller it looks like this.smaller:
[image: smaller]
is there any alternative to negative margin?
Or can I make it stable?
Sorry guys this is my first time asking question.
I searched everywhere for an answer.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You could try drawing the images with relative position inside a div of a set width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using percentages for the margins instead of px. Also, I've always had better luck with padding than margin in general, but I don't know that padding will fix the issue.

Comment: I've tried negative percentage and it actually works perfectly . thanks for the help.

Comment: Great - glad to hear that worked for you! Remember to accept the answer if that's what worked.